# entity framework working with entity properties that are null

Tags: entity-framework, nullpointerexception

In Entity framework, I am having entity properties which correspond to SQL Table columns which are ALLOW NULL = True in Database. When I use those properties in C#, if the value is null it gives exception. So how to handle this in EF, this happens for all the table columns that allow null.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming these columns are `Nullable` type in your .NET code, since they have `ALLOW NULL = True` in database. So, everytime you use these values, check for `PropertyName.HasValue()` which returns `false` whenever the property is null.

Comment: Is there is any other way, rather than checking every time for the property being null, meaning is there is any way the framework itself will take care when the column being null so that it will return the null eqiuvalent to the front end, ie, when a int column in null in db, the framework should return 0.

Comment: The EF already handles this i.e., if you have a null value in database then the value returned is null (though it may not return 0 for null values because null is not same as 0) it doesn't throw any exceptions unless you use some methods on that property for example if you use `.ToString()` method on the column. If you are trying to use any methods then you can do null check is using HasValue() method. I believe I am making myself clear.